# Spotfire's IronPython: Update document property in a loop

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I expect the script below to loop through the pages in Document.Pages, update the document property with the page title, and wait for 1 second. Meanwhile I'm keeping my eye on a Text Area with a Label for that document property, and I expect to see that Label change every second. Instead, the Label only changes once the script is finished, and the property contains the title of the last page in my document. I thought the "Execute in transaction" checkbox affects this, but I seem to get the same result whether it's checked or not. Is there a workaround so that I can see the document property being updated once per second?

```
import time

for p in Document.Pages:
    msg = 'Current Page = ' + p.Title
    Document.Properties["progress.message"] = msg
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the python scripts execute all at once before updating visuals you'd want to look at something like this article : https://spotfired.blogspot.com/2016/01/animating-visualizations.html

Using a button to run a script and take a document property that is incrementally increased on each click of the button using javascript. So a bit of a messy set up but should work.